# Como resolver erro "Array required, but (Classe) found."?

Tags: java

Crie ainda uma classe de teste onde deverá instanciar um objeto da classe "Carta" e seguidamente os objetos que deverão ser armazenados no array dessa classe.

```
Carta teste = new Carta();
for (int i = 0; i < teste.length; i++) 
{
    if (teste instanceOf Figuras) {}
}
```

Essa é uma parte do exercício que tenho que fazer. Já tenho o resto do programa feito, falta apenas esta parte porque está a dar o erro "Array required, but Carta found".

Eu percebo porque é que o erro está a acontecer, mas como é que o resolvo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro acontece pois você esta utilizando a propriedade *length* diretamente no objeto (`teste`) de sua classe `Carta`.

Ao invés disso, você pode acessar o array que pertence a sua classe (supondo que o mesmo esteja público e que já tenha sido inicializado) da seguinte maneira:

```
Carta teste = new Carta();
for (int i = 0; i < teste.arrayDesejado.length; i++) 
{
    if (teste.arrayDesejado[i] instanceof Figuras) {}
}
```

**Obs:** outra incongruência se deve ao uso do [instanceof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) (escrito inteiramente em minúsculo). No seu código, você está testando se `teste` é uma instância de `Figuras`, o que nunca vai ser verdade pois ele já é uma instância de `Carta`. O mesmo ocorre com meu exemplo acima: `arrayDesejado` possui um tipo pré-estabelecido em sua definição; portanto, como esse tipo é imutável, não seria conveniente testar se determinada posição do *array* guarda uma instância de uma classe ou subclasse específica.

Uma alternativa seria usar um [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) dentro de sua classe `Carta` para guardar os objetos:

```
ArrayList<Object> listaDeObjetos = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Depois, para checar quais objetos foram adicionados à lista você poderia usar um *loop* que percorresse todos os seus elementos:

```
for (Object obj : teste.listaDeObjetos) 
{
    if (obj instanceof Figuras) {}
}
```

Comment: Eu nesse usei só um exemplo, no caso que estou a trabalhar a classe `Carta` é na realidade uma classe de nome `Ginasio`, que é uma super classe, por isso é que faço uso do `instanceof`. Quanto ao `ArrayList`, eu realmente coloquei essa questão ao professor, mas ele disse que neste exercício queriam que fosse utilizado um array..